Issue in converting Blender FBZ File to USDZ for Reality Kit
I am creating a animation file for Reality composer using Blender version 3.3. I exported it as a fbx format. I am converting the fbx format to USDZ using Apples reality converter.
While converting the Animations are not working properly as we expected in fbx Format.It is working properly in Reality converter Preview. When importing to reality composer it is not working.
This issue comes only when i am using Normal bone connecting animations.It is not coming with weight painting rigging animation.
